# How to change property of parent element if at least one child selected?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a tree of nodes of type `LayerNode`. Where each node as children and parent reference.

I try to change property of parent if at least one child element has property `selected = true`.

```
  public recursiveSelectLayers(node: LayerNode) {
    if (node.children)
      node.children.forEach((childNode: LayerNode) => {
        childNode.parent = node;

        if (childNode?.parent?.selected)
          childNode.selected = childNode.parent.selected;

        if (childNode.selected && childNode.parent)
          childNode.parent.selected = childNode.selected;

        this.recursiveSelectLayers(childNode);
      });
  }
```

At the same time if parent is `selected` I need to set `selected` for all **immediate** children.

Problem is if one of children has `selected` the function above selects all children from last children to the root.

**My second attempt:**

```
  public recursiveSelectLayers(node: LayerNode) {
    if (node.parent && node.selected) node.parent.selected = node.selected;

    if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach((childNode: LayerNode) => {
        if (node?.selected) childNode.selected = node.selected;
        childNode.parent = node;
        this.recursiveSelectLayers(childNode);
      });
    }
  }
```

Case 1:

```
Parent 1 (selected)
   Child 1
   Child 2
   Child 3 (selected)
```

Case 2:

```
   Parent 1 (selected)
       Child 1 (selected)
       Child 2 (selected)
       Child 3 (selected)
```

Case 3:

```
   Parent 1 (selected)
       Child 1
       Child 2
       Child 3 (selected)
           Child 3.1 (selected)
```

Editing:

```
  public recursiveSelectLayers(node: LayerNode) {
    if (node.id) this.flatlayers.set(node.id, node);
    if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach(this.recursiveSelectLayers, this);
      node.selected =
        [...node.children].some((node) => node.selected) ||
        node?.parent?.selected;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Your question lacks a proper problem description.

Comment: Updated, check it out

Comment: Please remove all code parts not relevant for the question, like the line with the `id` stuff.

Comment: Done! I added some schemas

Comment: While this isn't directly related to your question, your first example especially overuses [option chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). You assign `childNode.parent = node;` and then say `if (childNode?.parent?.selected)` even though you know for a fact that `childNode.parent` has a value (and so does the compiler!). Also, in the case where you know but the compiler doesn't, there's the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

Comment: When a parent is selected, do you want to select only the *immediate* children?

Comment: Select only children below for this parent, not all in all tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this... but I'm testing it. Passed 4 cases.

```js
function recursiveSelectLayers(node) {
  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach((childNode) => {

      if (node.parent && node.selected) {
        node.parent.selected = true;
      }

      recursiveSelectLayers(childNode);
    });
  }

  if (node.parent && node.parent.selected) {
    node.selected = true;
  }

  return node
}

// tests:

var case1 = {
  selected: true,
  children: [{}, {}, {
    selected: true
  }]
}
case1.children[0].parent = case1;
case1.children[1].parent = case1;
case1.children[2].parent = case1;

var case2 = {
  selected: true,
  children: [{
    selected: true
  }, {
    selected: true
  }, {
    selected: true
  }]
}
case2.children[0].parent = case2;
case2.children[1].parent = case2;
case2.children[2].parent = case2;

var case3 = {
  selected: true,
  children: [{}, {}, {
    selected: true,
    children: [{
      selected: true
    }]
  }]
}
case3.children[0].parent = case3;
case3.children[1].parent = case3;
case3.children[2].parent = case3;
case3.children[2].children[0].parent = case3.children[2];

var case4 = {
  children: [{}, {}, {
    selected: true,
    children: [{}]
  }]
}
case4.children[0].parent = case4;
case4.children[1].parent = case4;
case4.children[2].parent = case4;
case4.children[2].children[0].parent = case4.children[2];

console.log(recursiveSelectLayers(case1))
console.log(recursiveSelectLayers(case2))
console.log(recursiveSelectLayers(case3))
console.log(recursiveSelectLayers(case4))
```

```html
<pre>
Case1: 
   Parent 1 (selected)
      Child 1
      Child 2
      Child 3 (selected)

Case 2:
   Parent 1 (selected)
       Child 1 (selected)
       Child 2 (selected)
       Child 3 (selected)

Case 3:
   Parent 1 (selected)
       Child 1
       Child 2
       Child 3 (selected)
           Child 3.1 (selected)
           
Case 4:
   Parent 1
       Child 1 
       Child 2
       Child 3 (selected)
           Child 3.1 
                     
</pre>
```

Comment: It does not work. I have updated the question

Comment: *"It does not work"* **is not at all a helpful problem description, ever.**

Comment: I opened a new question where shared a code to prove it does not work, see it please

Comment: For reference, it's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904711/how-to-fix-tree-iteration-logic)